I need to pull a date from a row if the vacation column has a number in it
I have a time card sheet.  I want to compose a short list of all the dates a person has used PTO/VAC and the amount they used on that date.
I have all the dates listed for the year in one column.  Then I have a value of 4 or 8 in the vacation column.
I already have the totals and what a person has left to use, but I need the short list of dates.
I have tried doing various index and match but have not been able to have it not return blank cells.
It is like a filter with out creating the table.  I can not find examples were numbers and dates are involved.  Only text.

Please post some sample data as markdown table in your question including expected result with given data. It seems =FILTER() might be a good choice to investigate.
